# object creation generates error in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm have this code and when I try to compile it it gives me an error saying that "name is already used by an existing object". But I don't have another object with this name.

```
drop type specii_inr;
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE specii_inr UNDER gestiune_zoo
    (specii_inrudite VARCHAR2(20),
     OVERRIDING member procedure afiseaza_animal)
    /
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE specii_inr AS
     OVERRIDING MEMBER PROCEDURE afiseaza_animal IS
     BEGIN
       dbms_output.put_line('Animale inrudite: '||specii_inrudite);
     END afiseaza_animal;
    END;
    /
```

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE specii_inr` should be `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE body specii_inr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `afiseaza_animal` procedure belongs to the type and you need to define it in the body of the type (using `CREATE TYPE BODY`) and *not* as a standalone procedure (using `CREATE PROCEDURE`).

```
DROP TYPE specii_inr;

CREATE TYPE specii_inr UNDER gestiune_zoo (
  specii_inrudite VARCHAR2(20),
  OVERRIDING member procedure afiseaza_animal
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY specii_inr AS
  OVERRIDING MEMBER PROCEDURE afiseaza_animal IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('Animale inrudite: '||specii_inrudite);
  END afiseaza_animal;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

Your procedure has the same name as your type, so when you try to create it you get the "Name is already used by an existing object error".

Try using a different name for your procedure e.g. specii_inr_proc